# Intuition for the identity $\epsilon_{ijk}\epsilon_{ilm}=\delta_{jl}\delta_{km}-\delta_{kl}\delta_{jm}$?

Tags: tensor-calculus, notation

One of the popular Kronecker delta and Levi-Cevita identities reads
$$\epsilon_{ijk}\epsilon_{ilm}=\delta_{jl}\delta_{km}-\delta_{kl}\delta_{jm}.$$

Now, is there an intuition or mnemonic that you use, that can help one learn these or similar mathematical identities more easily?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about advice for learning mathematical identities, not physics.

Comment: @ACuriousMind The title of my book that has these says, mathematical physics. I hope physics still finds mathematics relevant or have I missed some of the current developments in the field?

Comment: I'm saying that asking how to memorize things is not a physics question (asking how one should remember Newton's three laws is likewise off-topic because it isn't an actual physics question).

Comment: Yes, but it's a good enough resource for others, to know how actual physicists think about applying newton's laws in specific scenarios. Personally, I'd be grateful if you just leave my questions alone.

Comment: Completely off topic, imo. Where does it end? It's up to you learn this, no different from you having to learn  calculus.

Comment: @ Isomorphic. Please edit your question. No one is going to watch the video you posted. Better put your question in a more concrete form.

Comment: @count_to_10 I have specifed specific identitities and would like to know the intuition behind them. Personally, sometimes certain identities are aesthetically pleasing, so they don't take any effort to learn and sometimes some are just intuitive enough to remember in one go. Now, there can only so be so many of such identities I accept, but I would like to know if these ones belong to that particular list and I'm failing to see that and if not, it'd be a good resource for myself and others to know how others see such identities that can help one form an intuition behind them, even if purely

Comment: It looks like you got a good answer from Subramanya Hegde.   If you like it, please accept it.

Comment: I'd answer this question if it were posted on math.SE.

Comment: I've had questions closed, and the trick is to not take it personally. Is closure perfectly consistent? No. But it's not a big deal either. Nobody is attacking you, so there's no reason for you to be attacking others.

Comment: I've deleted a number of comments for being perilously close to personal attacks and certainly not in keeping with the "Be nice." policy, and others for being a rather misplaced, passive-aggressive attempt to make a point that merely ended up polluting the record. Take it to chat or to meta, or shrug it off and move on with life.

Comment: Crossposted to http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1874812/11127

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us say these indices are Euclidean indices. The only natural tensors are $\epsilon^{ijk}$ and $\delta_{ab}$(and it's inverse). Since you have contracted one index, the only natural terms you can write are on the ones you have written in the right hand side using $\delta_{ab}$ with appropriate antisymmetrization to have the same antisymmetry as the left hand side when indices are interchanged.

Edit:

You can similarly argue for the numerical factor by noting that $\epsilon^{ijk}$s take values $\pm1,0$ and arguing that for a given set of $j,k,l,m$ the term with only one value of $i$ is non zero in the sum over $i$ since $i\neq j,k,l,m$ and $j\neq k, l \neq m$

When I say $\delta_{ab}$ and $\epsilon^{abc}$ is natural, I mean that these are the two tensors that exist in Euclidean space without needing to specify any additional tensor field. i.e. In any Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^n$, we have a fully anti symmetric Levi Civita symbol $\epsilon^{a_1a_2...a_n}$ that transforms as a tensor.

Comment: Also, I think posting a thank you comment violates the comment policy of SE. If you like an answer you can mark your question as answered and that would be enough

Comment: Some people were nagging me to accept your answer, I just wanted to let you know that I liked your answer.

Comment: Be accepting the answer, they meant this. Not upvoting it. http://physics.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: What do you mean by Euclidean indices? I don't get the part about natural tensors choices also. Sorry

Comment: Also, I see from your other posts on the site, that you honestly know this stuff. So, if there are any resources you could refer me, I'd be very grateful. I'm sorry, I haven't studied classical field theory, so I wasn't able to understand your comment on this post either.

Comment: Also, if you could tell me how do you think/imagine such objects, so that you can intuitively glide through calculations at times. The way I currently imagine tensors etc. is like square/cubical/4d etc. matrices arising from some tensor products and operations defined on them, in a form only similar to matrix multiplication in Linear Algebra. Of course basis dependent etc. How do you think about this stuff while doing those insanely long calculations component by component? Even the one mentioned in my original post has 81 components, although not a tensor. Please help.

Comment: Intuition can not be taught with one answer but is developed by doing more and more calculations. By Euclidean indices I meant let us consider that we are working in Euclidean space and $i,j,k$ are indices corresponding to directions in this space. Metric in a Euclidean space is $\delta_{ab}$ and if no other field is given the only tensors you can think of are $\delta_{ab}$ and $\epsilon^{abc}$.

Comment: I finally get your answer. It is great. Thanks a ton. The real meat for me, is in the second part of it. However, you say epsilon tensor is natural to think of, is it because of the cross product you say so?

Comment: I have edited the answer to explain why they are more natural. If you need any more clarification, we can move this to chat

Answer (score 2):

Following the argument of Subramanya Hegde, one can write the product of two  Levi-Cevita tensor $\epsilon_{ijk}$ and $\epsilon_{lmn}$ as 
\begin{equation}
\epsilon_{ijk}\epsilon_{lmn} = \delta_{il}\delta_{jm}\delta_{kn}+\delta_{im}\delta_{jn}\delta_{kl}+\delta_{in}\delta_{jl}\delta_{km}-\delta_{il}\delta_{jn}\delta_{km}-\delta_{in}\delta_{jm}\delta_{kl}-\delta_{im}\delta_{jl}\delta_{kn}\tag{1}
\end{equation}
Its not hard to see to show from relation (1) that $\epsilon_{jik}\epsilon_{lmn}=-\epsilon_{ilk}\epsilon_{lmn}$.

Setting $i=l$ gives
$$\epsilon_{ijk}\epsilon_{imn}=\delta_{jm}\delta_{kn}-\delta_{jn}\delta_{km}$$